# How to import library javascript in component (within the component)?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**I am using angular 2 with angular cli**

I know how to import using angular-cli.json. However I want to import within component.

The reason is that the file is too large and I do not want it to be loaded at the initial system load.

How can I load an external library when a specific component loads?

My system will use a library to receive payment of my client. I need to import this library into my payment component: https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js

After import I need to use some functions of this imported file to generate a token. With this token I can carry out the payment transactions.

My problem is that I do not want to upload this file to the initial upload. I would like to load only when a particular route is called. exemple: /pay-signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [TypeScript 2.4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/) you've got the option to use an `import` statement within the code itself, you can write your own loader to load a library:

```
async getLib(name: string): Promise<any> {
    return await import(name);
}
```

You should wrap this around a `Resolve` service for any path where you use said library.

If you do not want to/can use the latest TypeScript, you can create a `script` tag and listen for the `load` event:

```
getLib(name: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
       let script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
       script.addEventListener('load', r => resolve());
       script.src = string;
       document.head.appendChild(script);      
    });    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll try to use this solution.